# How to split random generated array values in two separate array using numpy and random?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

how to create a vector called row_min that contains the minimum value for each of the 25 rows (this implies the shape of this vector will be (25,)) Create a vector called col_max that contains the maximum value for each of the 8 columns (col_max will be a vector of shape (8,))

I have developed the code and I'm new to vector concept, need some suggestions.

```
import random
import numpy

c = numpy.random.rand(25,8)
print("Random float array 25X8 between range of 0.0 to 1.0 \n")
print(c,"\n")
```

I didn't find the source to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the *axis* `np.max( .., axis=...)` should work on:

```
import random
import numpy as np

c = np.random.rand(5,3) # smaller for less output 
print(c,"\n")

print( np.max(c, axis=0)) # column
print( np.max(c, axis=1)) # row
```

Output:

```
[[0.47894278 0.80356294 0.34453725]
 [0.33802491 0.82795648 0.28438504]
 [0.46838701 0.73664987 0.82215448]
 [0.66245476 0.59981989 0.43837083]
 [0.28515865 0.86093323 0.92248524]] 

# axis 0 (columns)
[0.66245476 0.86093323 0.92248524]
# axis 1 (rows)
[0.80356294 0.82795648 0.82215448 0.66245476 0.92248524]
```

See [matrix.max()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.max.html?highlight=max#numpy.matrix.max) ... `min()` works the same.

Comment: I'm practicing lots of codes and trying to get most out of it to understand from the community as well as my personal code. I still got some problems to go to. But thank you for your help again.

Comment: @MAyur  happy to help. Maybe do some tutorials that explain stuff better, or read up in the API - most python/numpy/pandas stuff is very well covered in either tutorials or its documentation. wont help you again today to avoid getting looked at for voting fraud. have a nice day/night.